# Relationship database design - object specific many to many, do I solve with self join table or new table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, filemaker

Being new to relational database design, I am trying to clarify one piece of information to properly design this database. Although I am using Filemaker as the platform, I believe this is a universal question.

Using the logic of ideally having all one to many relationships, and using separate tables or join tables to solve these.

I have a database with multiple products, made by multiple brands, in multiple product categories. I also want this to be as scale-able as possible when it comes to reporting, being able to slice and dice the data in as many ways as possible since the needs of the users are constantly changing.

So when I ask the question "Does each Brand have multiple products" I get a yes, and "Does each product have multiple brands" the answer is no. So this is a one to many relationship, but it also seems that a self-join table might give me everything that I need.

This methodology also seems to go down a rabbit hole for other "product related" information such as product category, each product is tied to one product category, but only one product category is related to a product.

So I see 2 possibilities, make three tables and join them with primary and foreign keys, one for Brand, one for Product Category, and one for Products.

Or the second possibility is to create one table that has the brand and product category and product info all in one table (since they are all product related) and simply do self-joins and other query based tables to give me the future reporting requirements that will be changing over time.

I am looking for input from experiences that might point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: three tables... you need to try and normalize it.. you may even want to use more than three depending on the data and how much you need to slice and dice it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so more tables to reduce/eliminate redundancy, you cant have too many "one to many" tables in a relationship database.

Comment: if you are duplicating data in a table because another column has different data then its better to split that into another table :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where do you see a room for a self-join here. It seems to me you are saying: I have a table of products; each product has one brand and one (?) category. If that's the case then you need either three tables:

```
Brands -< Products >- Categories
```

or - in Filemaker only - you can replace either or both the Brands and the Categories tables with a value list (assuming you won't be renaming brands/categories and at the expense of some reporting capabilities). So really it depends on what type of information you want to get out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Could you ever want to store additional information about a brand (company URL, phone number, etc.) or about a product category (description, etc.)?

If the answer is yes, you *definitely* want to use three tables.  If you don't, you'll be repeating all that information for every single item that belongs to the same brand or same category.

If the answer is no, there is still an advantage to using three tables - it will prevent typos or other spelling inconsistencies from getting into your database.  For example, it would prevent you from writing a brand as "Coca Cola" for some items and as "Coca-Cola" for other items.  These inconsistencies get harder and harder to find and correct as your database grows.  By having each brand only listed once in it's own table, it will always be written the same way.

The disadvantage of multiple tables is the SQL for your queries is more complicated.    There's definitely a tradeoff, but when in doubt, normalize into multiple tables.  You'll learn when it's better to de-normalize with more experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want your solution to be scalable you need to parse and partition your data now. Otherwise you will be faced with the re-structuring of the solution down the road when the solution grows in size.  You will also be faced with parsing and relocating the data to new tables.  Since you've also included the SQL and MySQL tags if you plan on connecting Filemaker to an external data source then you will definitely need to up your game structurally.

Building everything in one table is essentially using Filemaker to do Excel work and it won't cut it if you are connecting to SQL, MySQL, etc.

Self join tables are a great tool.  However, they should really only be used for calculating small data points and should not be used as pivot points or foundations for your reporting features.  It can grow out of control as time goes on and you need to keep your backend clean.

Use summary and sub-summary reporting features to slice product based data.

For retail and general product management solutions, whether it's Filemaker/SQL/or whatever the "Brand" or "Vendor" is it's own table.  Then you would have a "Products" table (the match key being the "Brand ID").

The "Product Category" field should be a field in the "Products" table.  You can manage the category values by building a standard value list or building a value list based on a "Product Category" table.  The second scenario is better for long term administration.